# How to delete records in DB with mySQL using group by

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, sql-delete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Delete: can't specify target table for update in FROM clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/sql-delete-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)

I have one table only (call this table TAB), representing University exams. I have the following attributes: CourseName, CourseCode and year. I want to delete all courses that have a cardinality less than 100. If I type

```sql
select CourseName from TAB group by CourseName having count(CourseName) < 100;
```

I have an exact result. But if I want to delete this entries I try with

```sql
delete from TAB where CourseName not in (select CourseName from TAB group by CourseName having count(CourseName) > 100);
```

but the system returns an error:

> Error Code: 1093 You can't specify target table 'TAB' for update in FROM clause

How I have to delete these records?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see the answer at the following link.  It will solve your issue:

- [MySQL Error 1093 - Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/sql-delete-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)

Basically, you can't delete from (modify) the same table you use in the SELECT. There are ways around it documented at that page.

The following will work by making your nested `select` a temp table.

```
delete from TAB
where CourseName not in (select temp.CourseName
                         from (select t.CourseName
                               from TAB t
                               group by t.CourseName
                               having count(t.CourseName) > 100
                              ) as temp
                        )
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest ways is to create a temporary table from your first query, and then in a second statement delete all the courses not present in the temporary table.

Comment: Ok, how can I create a temp table?

Answer (score 0):

```
  $result=mysql_query("select CourseName from TAB group by CourseName having count(CourseName) < 100");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
mysql_query("delete from tab where courses='$row[0]'");
}
```

Comment: Deleting results individually uses more bandwidth and processing power on the SQL server's end. It requires downloading a list of maybe hundreds of thousands of rows that the web server does not need and then execute one hundred thousand additional SQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this may work?

```
DELETE FROM tab AS a 
INNER JOIN (select CourseName from TAB group by CourseName having count(Coursename)>100) as b
ON a.CourseName = b.coursename
```